# If statement isn't working during detecting the language to redirect the page

Tags: javascript, if-statement, browser, syntax

Code skips the if statement.

I've searched for a while now for the answer but couldn't find a solution, and since the similar questions are marked as duplicate I wanted to say these first.
So here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDocC1() {
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    var lang = ("en-US");
    if (lang=userLang){
    window.location.replace("http://karabatak.info");
    }else {window.location.replace("http://kontrabandapart.info");}
    }
    </script>
```

code chooses one direction to go (either one site or other) regardless of variables.

Comment: The statement is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the error

```
if (lang=userLang){
```

should be

```
if (lang == userLang){
```

Have a look at this

[Js operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: no, i've tried "==", also tried indexOf("en") and then lang>-". didn't work.

Comment: hey there  have you looked at jsFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/y7guro4s/1/

Comment: yes, it seems to be working, I guess when I last tried it I've stucked at the cache and overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `if` statement:

```
if (lang = userLang)
```

You're using the *assignment operator* (`=`) here - this assigns a value to a variable. You want to use the *equality / comparison operator* (`==`) - this tests whether one value is equal to another. Change your `if` statement to this:

```
if (lang == userLang)
```

And your code will work.

Comment: tahank you, that's how it is.